# Regex to hide html tags

Tags: apex, trigger, regular-expressions, apexrest, long-text-area

I have one field Long text in which I have to escape HTML tags,
I am able to escape HTML tags using REGEX but problem is if Content in field has gretaer than(<) character ,
this charcter is also getting escaped.

for Eg: String str='
 Number a < 5'
Output:Number a

regex function which I am using is: 
<.*?>
I tried using below Regex function also but couldnot solve the problem.
<.*?\>

Comment: What are you trying to cleanse?  This is a super complicated issue that can require several regular expressions.  You're likely better off handling this differently.

Comment: I have to replace HTML tags in a string

Comment: Specific tags or all tags?

Comment: All HTML Tags. <.*?> using this regex I am able to hide HTML tags, but if Content in field has greater than(<) character , this character is also getting escaped.